# How to remove duplicates from each month in PL/SQL

Tags: plsql

I have recently problem with duplicated values, occurring in one month.
I have one table with ONE product and different SUBSCRIBERS.
Product is subscription-based and sometimes happens, that costumer, in the period of one month activates and deactivates product several times - thus making several rows.
Costumer may have product activated for several months without change - thus there would be just one row per that period - starting date.
[I am adding picture, with current and desired results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIxQq.png)

**In this case, I need to get only one row per costumer per month, with MAX(start_date) as in pictures.**    As in picture. I have tried to use ROWNUM function, *but I do not know how to deal with one row each month condition.*

Thanks for any advice

Comment: In your picture i can see 2 rows for 1 customer. so you want 2 rows or one ?

Answer (score 0):

In the future, please include sample data and examples of what you have tried. Try this:

```
INSERT INTO targettable( customer_id
                       , subscription_product_id
                       , start_date )
      SELECT customer_id
           , subscription_product_id
           , MAX( start_date )
        FROM sourcetable
    GROUP BY customer_id
           , subscription_product_id
           , TRUNC( start_date, 'MM' )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove duplicates with `ROWID`

Look how to do that https://www.google.com/amp/s/m.wikihow.com/Delete-Duplicate-Records-in-Oracle%3famp=1